# python catch several exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I have some code that is calling several methods from multiple functions. Some of these methods may raise an exception. Each can raise a different type of exception. In my main script, I would like to log the exception and then just exit. So, no matter what the exception type, log it and exit

My question is this: is it better to list all the exceptions that might be generated, or just catch a generic Exception? Which is more pythonic?

example:

```
try:
    some_stuff()
except (Exc1, Exc2, Exc3) as exc:
    loger.exception(exc)
```

or this:

```
try:
    some_stuff()
except Exception as exc:
    loger.exception(exc)
```

Comment: Generally it's much better to be specific with your exceptions, so you can handle them better. In addition, broadly speaking, when a function can't do what it was intended to, it should terminate.

Comment: @kukac But the OP is not planning to handle the exception in any way, apart from logging them into log file. With explicit exceptions you will not be able catching unexpected ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except):

> Because except: catches all exceptions, including SystemExit,
>   KeyboardInterrupt, and GeneratorExit (which is not an error and should
>   not normally be caught by user code), using a bare except: is almost
>   never a good idea. In situations where you need to catch all “normal”
>   errors, such as in a framework that runs callbacks, you can catch the
>   base class for all normal exceptions, Exception.  Unfortunately in Python 2.x it is
>   possible for third-party code to raise exceptions that do not inherit from Exception, so
>   in Python 2.x there are some cases where you may have to use a bare except: and manually > re-raise the exceptions you don’t want to catch.

In general, it is better to catch explicit exceptions. In Python 2, how you are doing it can result in exceptions you still don't catch if an external module is throwing something that doesn't inherit exception.

By catching explicit exceptions you are able to handle errors you know can occur. If you catch all, your application could do something unexpected and you may handle it incorrectly.

Additionally, do you really want to catch someone using Ctrl+C to end your program?

Comment: Good answer but the code won't catch those exceptions (`SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, `GeneratorExit`) because he's using `except Exception`, so I think that quote is a little bit "off-topic".

Answer (score 3):

Your plan to catch exception in main code, log it and terminate is good one.

There could be exceptions, which are fine and do not mean, you shall consider them as problem, e.g. `KeyboardInterrupt`

The strategy could be:

- first, catch all the exceptions, which you expect to be fine and `pass`
- then catch general `Exception`, log it and terminate.

The code could look like:

```
try:
    some(stuff) # ...
# First, resolve expected exceptions
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
# Finally, log unexpected ones
except Exception as exc:
    logger.exception(exc)
    return # time to terminate
```

## When is catching exceptions explicitly a failure

The advice to be better by explicitly catching all expected exceptions comes short in case an unexpected exception happens. Your plan to catch whatever comes to log file sounds good and provide enough information for resolving the problems later on.

Imagine, you have a daemon, which shall run and run. Under some conditions, it might fail.

With only expecting explicit exception, it may happen, unexpected exception happens, no `expect`
would have a chance to log this to a log file, stacktrace would be printed to stdout and forgotten
and program terminates.

This is clear and very reasonable use case for catching exception generally.

Answer (score 1):

In all languages, times, and places it is better to specify specific exceptions. That way you won't mask a condition you didn't expect to. NEVER catch `Exception` in production code unless you have a very, very good reason, or your handler is truly generic. An example of a suitably generic handler is one which logs, performs cleanup, and reraises.

Comment: That is what I thought.

Comment: @Mark Does that imply that someone is trying to get you to catch generic exceptions?

Comment: Not really, just trying to ensure that I am doing it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Take a note out of Tim Peter's book:

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
...
```

Explicit is better than implicit.  It's more "pythonic" to write out the possible exceptions.